How to Implement Subresource Integrity (SRI) in Script and Link Tags in Nuxt.js for Enhanced Security?
I'm attempting to add the integrity attribute to the script and link tags at build time by using the build:manifest hook in a custom module. However, the integrity attribute is not being added after the project is built.
import { createHash } from 'node:crypto'
import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises'
import { defineNuxtModule } from '@nuxt/kit'

// Module options TypeScript interface definition
export interface ModuleOptions {
  enabled: boolean
  hash: string
  crossorigin: string
}

export default defineNuxtModule<ModuleOptions>({
  meta: {
    name: 'nuxt-sri',
    configKey: 'sri',
    compatibility: {
      nuxt: '^3.0.0',
    },
  },
  // Default configuration options of the Nuxt module
  defaults: {
    enabled: true,
    hash: 'sha384',
    crossorigin: 'anonymous',
  },
  setup(_options, _nuxt) {
    _nuxt.hook('build:manifest', async (manifest) => {
      if (!_options.enabled) {
        return
      }
      // Generate SRI hashes for each asset
      for (const asset of Object.values(manifest)) {
        if (asset.src) {
          try {
            const data = await readFile(asset.src) // Make sure this is the correct path
            const hash = createHash(_options.hash).update(data).digest('base64')
            asset.integrity = `${_options.hash}-${hash}`
            asset.crossorigin = _options.crossorigin
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to process', asset.src, ':', error.message)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  },
})


Have you tried this? https://nuxt-security.vercel.app/documentation/utils/subresource-integrity

@kissu I haven't tried this yet. I'll look into it.

@kissu I've tested the package and found that it only works with local files. Currently, I am using AWS S3 and CloudFront to serve the script and CSS files. Unfortunately, the package does not add the integrity attribute when files are served from a CDN.

What? Big doubts about that one, the package is probably not dumb for it to only work locally. Did you ask on GitHub to double-check?
